# Constraint break on orientation changed

Tags: swift, swift3, autolayout, swift4

I've noticed werid break constraint on orientation changed. I have stack with couple of views insiade - the stack on portrait position have `distribution = .fill` and `axis = .vertical` while orientation going to change inside `willTransition` For Landscape I am changing `distribution = fillEqually` and `axis = .horizontal`. The constraint breaks while I deactivated it.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0096670 UIStackView:0x103d50f70.height == 168.75   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0096cb0 UICollectionView:0x1048b3e00.height == 40.02   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0095e00 'UISV-alignment' UIStackView:0x103d42150.bottom == UICollectionView:0x1048b3e00.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0095cc0 'UISV-alignment' UIStackView:0x103d42150.top == UICollectionView:0x1048b3e00.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c009d420 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x103d50f70.top == UIStackView:0x103d42150.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c00967b0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIStackView:0x103d42150]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':UIStackView:0x103d50f70 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c0096cb0 UICollectionView:0x1048b3e00.height == 40.02   (active)>
```

I know that height constraint of the `UICollectionView` is breaking, but why ? When I deactivated it, why it breaks ?

Here is a code:

```
// Extension of `UIStackView`
    func custom(axis: UILayoutConstraintAxis, distribution: UIStackViewDistribution) {
            self.distribution = distribution
            self.axis = axis
            self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }

    // Global variable in VC.
    var collectionHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!



lazy var stackAnimationHelper: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.addArrangedSubview(self.otherStack)
        stack.addArrangedSubview(self.collectionView)
        stack.custom(axis: .vertical, distribution: .fill)
        return stack
    }()

    // ViewDidLoaded.
    collectionHeight = collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightUnit * 25)
    collectionHeight.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
    collectionHeight.isActive = true


override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
    let isLandscape = UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
    let isPortrait = UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        if isLandscape {
            self.collectionHeight.isActive = false
            self.stackAnimationHelper.distribution = .fillEqually
            self.stackAnimationHelper.axis = .horizontal
            self.stackAnimatorHelperHeight.constant = self.heightUnit * 45
        } else if isPortrait {
            self.collectionHeight.isActive = true
            self.stackAnimationHelper.distribution = .fill
            self.stackAnimationHelper.axis = .vertical
            self.stackAnimatorHelperHeight.constant = self.heightUnit * 61
        }
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        self.stackAnimationHelper.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.stackAnimationHelper.setNeedsLayout()
    }, completion: { _ in
        if isPortrait {
        }
    })
}
```

What I could missing ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the calls to `invalidateLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` and `setNeedsLayout`. Changes in constraints are already automatically animated during the transition, so you should not be trying to subvert the layout process by forcing another round of layout.

Comment: @matt Done, Seems it helps but gotta look deeper on the layout. Btw. `invalidateLayout` is needed to recalculate layout. If I don't do it, the method: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` won't be called on Landscape orientation. Only on Portrait. Werid :c

Comment: @matt I've left only two things : `self.stackAnimationHelper.layoutIfNeeded()` and `invalidateLayout`. Otherwise it crashes with: `reason: 'negative sizes are not supported in the flow layout'`